# What is similarities and difference between statistical inference and hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

What is similarities and difference between statistical inference and hypothesis testing?

I am confused between those

Comment: The [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference#Examples_of_frequentist_inference) is a subset of the [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inferentiel statistic is a type of statistic, on statistic we have two types descriptive statistics and inferentiel statistics. the last one is used to draw conclusion from population. statistic testing is the way used to draw conclusion. to recap descriptive statistic to describe population using graphs and tables while inferentiel statistic used to draw conclusion by setting hypothesis and testing it to make some conclusion